# Magento 2.2.3 - Call to a member function getProductCollection() on null

Tags: magento2.2.3

When I call to member function `getProductCollection()` It gives me a null error.

Error is:

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getProductCollection() on null in /media/webdata/var/www-data/html/ext_dev/m2/boughttogether/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

My file is `app/code/Vendor/BoughtTogether/Model/Product.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\BoughtTogether\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    /**
     * Retrieve array of bought type products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBoughttypeProducts() 
    {
        if (!$this->hasBoughtTypeProducts()) {
            $products = [];
            $collection = $this->getBoughtTypeProductCollection(); 
                foreach ($collection as $product) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            $this->setBoughttypeProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('boughttype_products');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve bought type products identifiers
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBoughttypeIds() 
    {
        if (!$this->hasBoughttypeProductIds()) {
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($this->getBoughttypeProducts() as $product) {
                $ids[] = $product->getId();
            }
            $this->setBoughttypeProductIds($ids);
        }
        return $this->getData('boughttype_product_ids');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve collection bought type product
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection
     */
    public function getBoughtTypeProductCollection() 
    {
        $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useBoughttypeLinks()->getProductCollection()->setIsStrongMode();
        $collection->setProduct($this);
        return $collection;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve collection bought type link
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Collection
     */
    public function getBoughtTypeLinkCollection() 
    {
        $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useBoughttypeLinks()->getLinkCollection();
        $collection->setProduct($this);
        $collection->addLinkTypeIdFilter();
        $collection->addProductIdFilter();
        $collection->joinAttributes();
        return $collection;
    }        
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: app/code/Vendor/BoughtTogether/model/roduct.php ?

Comment: yes but use in my custom module ?

Comment: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation